# How to update a map within a map in 1 LOC

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an initially empty nested map in the following format:

```
let nestedMap = new Map<number, Map<number, string>>();
```

And I would like to update the nested map in 1 line of code if possible.

```
nestedMap.set(1, ???)
```

The following approach compiles but overrides the child map every time:

```
nestedMap.set(1, create new map here)
```

Comment: `nestedMap.get(outerKey).set(innerKey, value)`?

Comment: this only works when the outerKey is already there, in my case the map is initially empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
!nestedMap.has(key) ? nestedMap.set(key, new Map()) : nestedMap.get(key).set(key2, value)
```

Comment: yes, I think ternary operator is the only way on how to write it in 1 LOC. Thanks